# Autoload a view on every page with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have my views split up basically between three (3) files:

```
-- Header file 
$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);

-- Main Body file 
$this->load->view('login_view', $data);

-- Footer file 
$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
```

Now I just recently started building, but I've noticed it's really annoying to retype the header and footer on every controller to tell it to load. Is there a way to automatically load the `header` and `footer` view on every request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with `library`.

Create a new `library` file called template.php and write a function called load_template. In that function, use above code.

```
public function load_template($view_file_name,$data_array=array()) {

$ci = &get_instatnce();

$ci->load->view("header");

$ci->load->view($view_file_name,$data_array);

$ci->> load->view("footer");

}
```

You have to load this library in `autoload` file in config folder. so you don't want to load in all controller.

You can call

```
$this->template->load_template("index",$data_array);
```

If you want to pass date to view file, then you can send via $data_array

Answer (score 2):

I found an article long time ago, but i can't seem to find it now, basically the author, (which i forgot) override the showing of output. this method of output will access your views regarding the given `controller/method` and will try to search in your views directory automatically.

**Use at your own risk**

**Application/core/MY_COntroller.php**

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------**

```
 class MY_Controller Extends CI_Controller
 {
      protected $layout_view = 'layouts/application'; // default
      protected $content_view =''; //data
      protected $view_data = array(); //data to be passed

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function _output($output)
  {
    if($this->content_view !== FALSE && empty($this->content_view)) $this->content_view = $this->router->class . '/' . $this->router->method;

    $yield = file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/' . $this->content_view . EXT) ? $this->load->view($this->content_view, $this->view_data, TRUE) : FALSE ;

    if($this->layout_view)
    {
        $html = $this->load->view($this->layout_view, array('yield' => $yield), TRUE);
        echo $html;
    }
  }

}
```

**Application/views/layouts/layout.php**

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>master layout</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- this variable yeild is important-->
<div><?=$yield;?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what i use to create my template. Basically you need a directory structure as follows.

+Views
|+layouts
||-layout.php

the `layout.php` will serve as your master template

**How to use?**

extend the controller

```
class User Extends MY_Controller
{
   public function create_user()
   {
    //code here
   }
   public function delete_user()
  {
    //use a different master template
    $this->layout_view = 'second_master_layout';
  }
  public function show_user()
  {
    //pass the data to the view page
    $this->view_data['users'] = $users_from_db;

  }
}
```

Just create directory in your views and name it with the controller name i.e **user** then inside it add a file you named your method i.e **create_user**

So now your Directory structure would be

**+Views

| +layouts

| |-layout.php

| |-second_master_layout.php

| +user

| |-create_user.php**

Just Edit the code to give you a dynamic `header` or `footer`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple example which i always do with my CI project.

Pass the body part as a `$main` variable on controller's function

```
    function test(){
    $data['main']='pages/about_us'; // this is the view file which you want to load
    $data['something']='some data';// your other data which you may need on view
    $this->load->view('index',$data);
}
```

now on the view load the `$main` variable

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <?php $this->load->view('includes/header');?> 

    <div id="body">
   <?$this->load->view($main);?>
    </div>

    <?php $this->load->view('includes/footer');?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In this way you can always use `index.php` for your all the functions just value of `$main` will be different.
Happy codeing

Answer (score 1):

Using MY_Controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public $template_dir;
    public $header;
    public $footer;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $template_dir = 'templates'; // your template directory
        $header = 'header';
        $footer = 'footer';

        $this->template_dir = $template_dir;
        $this->header = $header;
        $this->footer = $footer;
    }

    function load_views ($main, $data = [], $include_temps = true) {
        if ($include_temps = true) {
             $this->load->view('$this->template_dir.'/'.$this->header);
             $this->load->view($main);
             $this->load->view('$this->template_dir.'/'.$this->footer);
        } else {
            $this->load->view($main);
        }
    }
}
```

Then load it like: `$this->load_views('login_view', $data);`

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on this topic on ellislab forums. Please take a look. It may help you.

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/86991/

**Alternative way:** Load your header and footer views inside the concern body view file. This way you can have batter control over files you want to include in case you have multiple headers and footer files for different purposes. Sample code shown below.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <?php $this->load->view('header');?> 

    <div id="body">
    body
    </div>

    <?php $this->load->view('footer');?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```